# How many types of database are there?

Tags: database

My question is that how many type of database are there?

I have searched some sources:

- [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database): it has lots of example of database but I don't know what type that database belongs to: in-memory database, active database, cloud database, Data warehouses...
- [here](http://www.my-project-management-expert.com/different-types-of-databases.html): it doesn't have graph database and lack of example of each database type.

I know only some types of database: rational database, graph database, network database, workdsheet database.

Is there any more type of database? Please divide into subcategories and give me some references and examples of each type (Oracle SQL, MySql, Excel, Access...). Thank you!

Comment: Can they be divided into groups?

Comment: What's the purpose of the question?  It's like asking how many types of automobiles there are - how do you define a "type"?

Comment: Some types of database: graph database, document database, cloud... It's not "how many brand names of database?" like sql server, mysql, sqlite...

Answer (score 2):

Please take a look at this:
[database](https://dzone.com/articles/spanner-globally-distributed)

[image]

I can only explain Non-relational and Relational the most common.
Relational Database - It is some thing like they have tables and data on those tables are related. Like for example you can get data from them using `join`.

Meanwhile, Non-Relational database are commonly store data in object structure. like this:

```
 {
    "name":"James",
    "age":21
 }
```

Comment: This image is exactly what I'm asking for. But can you give me some details of each type?

Comment: i updated my answer.

Comment: what about the others? The subtypes (nosql and Newsql)?